# How to download protobuf-socket-rpc maven repository?

Tags: java, maven, grpc-java

I am trying to download the `protobuf-socket-rpc` repository so that I could use classes like

```
com.googlecode.protobuf.socketrpc.RpcConnectionFactory;
```

in java. My maven file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"      
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>GroovyExample</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>MMAMatcherGroovyTest</name>

    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.protobuf.socketrpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>protobuf_socketrpc</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

however, `mvn install` command first returns a warning:

```
[WARNING] The POM for com.googlecode.protobuf.socketrpc:protobuf_socketrpc:jar:1.3.2
is missing, no dependency information available
```

and later an error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project GroovyExample: Could not resolve dependencies for 
project com.example:GroovyExample:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find 
com.googlecode.protobuf.socketrpc:protobuf_socketrpc:jar:1.3.2 in 
http://maven2:8081/repository/neurotechnology/ was cached in the local repository, 
resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of neurotec has elapsed
or updates are forced
```

I am working in a company and maven first attempts to download the repository from our local database. **How to update the `pom.xml` file such that maven would also download the `protobuf-socket-rpc` repository**?

Comment: Same as answer below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/60623427/1007926): https://code.google.com/archive/p/protobuf-socket-rpc/
Source: https://code.google.com/archive/p/protobuf-socket-rpc/source

Answer (score 1):

i can't find `protobuf_socketrpc` artifact on maven central (the error message agrees with me). is this correct artifact name? or it is locally (maven local or your company's maven) published?

i found the library on github: https://github.com/sdeo/protobuf-socket-rpc/blob/master/java/pom.xml. it doesn't look like that library is published. you need to build it locally to resolve it.

```
git clone https://github.com/sdeo/protobuf-socket-rpc.git
cd protobuf-socket-rpc/java
#edit pom.xml to use protobuf-java 2.4.1 (2.4.0 is not published)
mvn install
```

after install to local maven, you should be able to build the example above.

Comment: That's the library I was talking about it. The problem is I can't install it locally, because when I submit the code to the code base, the automatic tests will run and they will not have the repo installed locally.

Comment: well if you want to the CI pass, you need to publish that library to your company's artifactory. Otherwise, even if you submit the code, other people in your company cannot build.

Answer (score 0):

Maven looks out for list of available repositories to look the jar into, from local pom.xml and settings.xml.

In your case it is searching from http://maven2:8081/repository/neurotechnology/.
Add the repository from which the jar can be downloaded in the repositories tag of local pom.xml or global settings.xml